# .NET Maui HorizontalStackLayout expand to fill remaining window

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

I am trying to design an interface where there is a pane on the left and a another pane that expands to fit the remaining space.  I attempted to do this with a `HorizontalStackLayout`, but no matter what I do, I can't get the second pane to appear without setting a specific `WidthRequest`. This is a demonstration of how I want it to look:

[image]

This is what I am trying, but no combination of options seems to work:

```
<HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Green" HorizontalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="200"></BoxView>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></BoxView>
</HorizontalStackLayout>
```

This is all I ever get in Maui without setting an explicit width:[image]

I have tried Start, StartAndExpand, FillAndExpand, nothing works.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like I was able to accomplish my goal by using a Maui `Grid`.  It seems there was discussion [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/3362), stating the following:

> With this pull request I am proposing the following:
>
> 1. The "AndExpand" options will not go into MAUI Core.
> 2. The "AndExpand" options in Controls will be marked Obsolete
> 3. The Controls implementation of StackLayout will, for the time being, honor the "AndExpand" options. We may choose to remove that capability in the future.
> 4. No new form of the "AndExpand" options will be added to any future versions of Core or Controls.
>
> This pull request marks all of the "AndExpand" LayoutOptions in Controls as Obsolete. Current usages are preserved with warnings disabled.
>
> The pull request also adds "AndExpand" legacy capabilities to the new StackLayout. When the new StackLayout detects the use of "AndExpand" it will drop into a separate mode which lays out child views as expected. VerticalStackLayout and HorizontalStackLayout do not honor "AndExpand" - only StackLayout does this. This is to ease the transition for existing Xamarin.Forms applications.
>
> All of the functionality provided by "AndExpand" is already available to layouts via the Grid, so no new attached properties or other StackLayout->specific properties are required.

This is the solution:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Green" Grid.Column="0" />
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

This results in the following layout:
[image]

Comment: Should the second ColumnDefinition have a Width set?

Answer (score 2):

From what I have seen in the .Net Maui Git branch change comments - both the horizontal and vertical stack layouts ignore any layout options that have "andexpand" in them.  In my project, in needed to convert every thing that used 'andexpand' back to a regular stack layout with the orientation set to horizontal or vertical as needed.  Then the 'andexpand' options were respected.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/layouts?view=net-maui-8.0#stacklayout) both the **VerticalStackLayout** and **HorizontalStackLayout** ignore `*AndExpand` suffixes. This is a change in behavior from the **StackLyout** from Xamarin.Forms. However, for backwards compatibility **StackLayout** still behaves the same but if you use `AndExpand` you will get a warning.